# Chainer: ParallelUpdater performance vs MultiprocessUpdater

Tags: chainer

I'd like to train a CNN on the CIFAR10 dataset with chainer on multiple GPUs on a single node. I tried adapting [this example](https://github.com/chainer/chainer/blob/master/examples/cifar/train_cifar.py) to use ParallelUpdater, in a manner identical to [the mnist data parallel example](https://github.com/chainer/chainer/blob/master/examples/mnist/train_mnist_data_parallel.py#L53-L60) but training performance was very poor -- slower than training on one GPU, even though all 8 GPUs were being utilized. I changed to MultiprocessUpdater and performance (iters/sec) was much better.

Bad:

```
num_gpus = 8
chainer.cuda.get_device_from_id(0).use()
train_iter = chainer.iterators.SerialIterator(train, batch_size)

if num_gpus > 0:
    updater = training.updater.ParallelUpdater(
        train_iter,
        optimizer,
        devices={('main' if device == 0 else str(device)): device for device in range(num_gpus)},
    )
else:
    updater = training.updater.StandardUpdater(train_iter, optimizer, device=0)
```

Good:

```
num_gpus = 8

devices = range(num_gpus)

train_iters = [chainer.iterators.MultiprocessIterator(i, batch_size, n_processes=num_gpus) \
               for i in chainer.datasets.split_dataset_n_random(train, len(devices))]
test_iter = chainer.iterators.MultiprocessIterator(test, batch_size, repeat=False, n_processes=num_gpus)
device = 0 if num_gpus > 0 else -1  # -1 indicates CPU, 0 indicates first GPU device.

if num_gpus > 0:
    updater = training.updaters.MultiprocessParallelUpdater(train_iters, optimizer, devices=range(num_gpus))
else:
    updater = training.updater.StandardUpdater(train_iters[0], optimizer, device=device)
```

I also ran this benchmarking scripts with 8 GPUs, using the ParallelUpdater, but performance was also very poor: https://github.com/mitmul/chainer-cifar10/blob/master/train.py

My question is: how can I get good performance from ParallelUpdater, and what might I be doing wrong with it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using multiple GPUs, there is some overhead for communicating, so each iteration speed could be slower.
If you using data parallel method, you can use much more large batch size and large learning rate, it could accelerate your training.

Comment: Ah, I see. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find any combination of batch size and learning rate that sped up learning significantly (at least not near linear, which is what I was hoping).

Answer (score 1):

I am not so familiar with `ParallelUpdater`, so my understanding might be wrong.

I guess the purpose of `ParallelUpdater` is not for the speed performance, instead its main purpose is to use memory efficiently to compute large batch gradient.

When reading the source code, model update is done in python for loop, so due to the GIL (Global Interpreter Lock) mechanism, I guess its computation itself is not done in parallel.
https://github.com/chainer/chainer/blob/master/chainer/training/updaters/parallel_updater.py#L118

As written, you can use `MultiprocessUpdater` if you want to get benefit of speed performance by using multiple GPU.

Also, you can consider using ChainerMN which is extension library for multi-GPU training with chainer.

- [github](https://github.com/chainer/chainermn)
- [documentation](http://chainermn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/overview.html)

Comment: "so due to the GIL (Global Interpreter Lock) mechanism, I guess its computation itself is not done in parallel. " I see, that makes sense. I'll stick with MultiprocessParallelUpdater for speed -- for now, I'm trying to make sure learning is fast on one node without needing MPI. (Since chainermn and MultiprocessParallelUpdater both use NCCL, I expect similar performance though)